# How to read and write Visio Shape Data with Python

Tags: python, visio, win32com

When inspecting a cell in a Visio shape the following code doesn't return the expected values:

```
costVal= shpObj1.CellsU("Prop.Cost")
print (costVal)
```

[*Note - this is a summary of a question that was deleted while I was answering it, but it's a useful question so I thought I'd ask and answer it*.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get to the value of a ShapeSheet cell in Visio you have interogate one of the cell's [Result properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.cell.result).

```
import os
import win32com.client

from win32com.client import constants

# this sample assumes that Visio is running, that the ActiveWindow
# is a Drawing window and that the Selection.PrimaryItem
# is a 'Decision' shape from the 'Basic Flowchart Shapes' stencil

# get the running app
appVisio = win32com.client.GetActiveObject("Visio.Application")

# selection gets you the 1 or more selected shapes and
# the PrimaryItem returns the main / primary item in that selection
# or null if the selection is empty
targetShp = appVisio.ActiveWindow.Selection.PrimaryItem

# set the cell
targetShp.CellsU("Prop.Cost").FormulaU = "=2.50"

# read the cell using its 'internal units' result property
print(targetShp.CellsU("Prop.Cost").ResultIU)
```

Comment: Hi guys,
I manage to get all vso_shape objects from my visio and read their fields (Name/text/spatial_neighbours)

i cannot seem to read the Shape Data which i added in visio as a user by "right-click shape"->"Data"->"Define Shape Data"

i've tried to read the documentation and use .CellsU but nothing worked so far, i would greatly appreciate your help

Comment: No doubt you're solved by now, but you may need to check if the cell exists locally (ie not just inherited from the master) and you can do this with `Shape.CellExistsU` See this link for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape.cellexistsu